# regex for 2 different condition

Tags: java, regex

In my Kafka connect sink connector, Im consuming the topics with this regex `mysql-db01.(.*)` Now I'm facing an issue by adding one more condition for excluding a topic.

I have a String called `mysql-db01.schema-changes.mysql`.

Can someone help me with the regex patten to include all `mysql-db01.*` but exclude `mysql-db01.schema-changes.mysql`?

Comment: Regarding, 'mysql-db01.*', do you mean a literal '.*' or are you saying 'mysql-db01<anything but schema-changes.mysql>

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you want to match "mysql-db01." followed by anything but "sche" ("sche" is used in place of your "schema-changes.mysql" for breivity--hopefully, you'll see the logic and transpose it accordingly).

```
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$# testing answer to stackoverflow's questiong #68623429...  
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01.sche' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been denied
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01.Xsche' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
mysql-db01.Xsche
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been allowed
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01.scXhe' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
mysql-db01.scXhe
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been allowed
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01.scheX' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
mysql-db01.scheX
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been allowed
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01.scheXX' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
mysql-db01.scheXX
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been allowed
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01.XXsche' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
mysql-db01.XXsche
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been allowed
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db02.sche' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been denied
Mac_3.2.57$echo 'mysql-db01xsche' | egrep '^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s].*|s[^c].*|sc[^h].*|sch[^e].*|sche..*)'
Mac_3.2.57$# should've been denied
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Comment: Or equivalently:^mysql-db01\.(.{0,3}$|[^s]|s[^c]|sc[^h]|sch[^e]|sche.).*

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this, rather than jam it all into one regex.

Answer (score 0):

/
mysql-db01.(?!schema-changes).*
/
g

- mysql-db01 matches the characters mysql-db01 literally (case sensitive)
  . matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)
- Negative Lookahead (?!schema-changes)
  Assert that the Regex below does not match
  schema-changes matches the characters schema-changes literally (case sensitive)
  . matches any character (except for line terminators)
- matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  Global pattern flags
  g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)